# English emailing custom: should middle name be included in the beginning of a mail?

Tags: email

When emailing someone with a middle name, should people include the recipient's middle name at the beginning of the email or not? What are the implications for both?

For example, the two options are `Dear Mr. John J. Smith` or `Dear Mr. John Smith`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it was a very formal email I would first write the person's name, ad designation, in full, and then address them Dear Mr, or Dear Ms etc. e.g.

**John J. Smith,**

**Chief Education Officer,**

**South Borsetshire Borough Council**.

**Dear Mr Smith,**

This could be written Dear Sir, Dear Madam etc. as appropriate, depending on the level of formality.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be that formal , write him a letter and send it via the post office.

For an email, you do not need an address line—if you send it to his e-mail address, he will get it!

Start off with

Dear Mr/Professor/President/Whatever Smith:

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your first sentence. The day will inevitably come when there will be no post-office. And why should delivery be delayed for a day, just because it is a formal letter. The main problem with email, as regards formal and legal correspondence, is that one has no proof of delivery. Singapore intends to have a system of registered email addresses, so that anything sent to such an address, e.g. from the tax authority, the courts etc, is deemed to have been received. Whether societies such as ours will ever accept such authoritarian a thing is at best uncertain.

Comment: Interesting point. But I fail to see what "proof of delivery" has to do with the formality or lack thereof in addressing the recipient. Like it or not, e-mail is simply not as formal a medium as smail-mail, and is not likely to become so. Adding formality to e-mail, unfortunately, marks one not as exceptionally courteous, but as mildly-to-hopelessly old-fashioned.

Comment: If I am writing to a company that has failed to deliver a product, for which I have paid money, that will be a formal letter and may well end by my saying that if I do not receive the goods in three working days I shall institute proceedings in the County Court. I am unlikely to begin it with 'Dear Charlie, Where is that TV I paid for' am I ? Indeed any business letter from me will be formal. If 'proof of delivery' is paramount I will use the post. If it is not essential I may use email. But if it deals with a serious business matter e.g. complaint, formality seems appropriate.

Comment: Very well. Be as formal as you like. It might well carry some weight with some of the more educated customer-service staff, if there are any.

Comment: I tend to avoid Customer Service Departments, if I can. If I am seriously inconvenienced and getting nowhere with a complaint I send a formal well-written letter addressed personally to the Chairman, or Chief Executive of the company at their Registered Office address. I mark on the envelope, for example, " For the personal attention of W.Gates Esq. (To be opened by addressee only). The letter goes by Recorded Delivery. So far this procedure has not failed me, and sometimes brings complimentary gifts and ex-gratia payments for my inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

*Dear Mr. John J. Smith or Dear Mr. John Smith.*

.

In Britain, these are possible as a salutation:

*Dear Sir*,

*Dear Mr (Dr, Professor, General, etc) Smith*,

*Dear John*

.

In certain male circles in the past, this was appropriate:

*Dear Smith,*

*My dear Smith*

I doubt if anybody uses that form of address these days.

.

Most people consider this  not natural, though it is not uncommon in promotional material:

*Dear John Smith*

.

These are simply wrong:

*Dear Mr John J Smith*,

*Dear John J Smith*,

*Dear J Smith*,

*Dear Mr J Smith*,

*Dear J Smith*,

*Dear J J Smith*

.

Between good friends, of course many personal salutations may be used.